# How to move elements with Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) to[L, l=\(L_1\)] (0, 4);
    \draw (2, 0) to[C, l=\(C_1\), *-*] (2, 4);
    \draw (2, 4) to[R, l=\(R_1\), *-*] (4, 4);
    \draw (4, 0) to[C, l=\(C_2\), *-*] (4, 4);
    \draw (6, 0) to[R, l=\(R_2\), *-] (6, 2);
    \draw[fill=black] (6, 2) to[diode, l=\(D_1\), -*] (6, 4);
    \draw (8, 0) to[R, n=R3,  *-] (8, 2);
    \node[right] at (R3.s) {\(R_3\)};
    \draw[fill=black] (8, 4) to[diode, l=\(D_2\), *-] (8, 2);
    \node[op amp, xscale=-1, yscale=-1] (opamp) at (12, 2) {};
    \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 0)$) to[short, *-] (opamp.out);
    \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 0)$) -- ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 1.2)$);
    \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 0)$) -- ($(opamp.out) + (-1, -1.2)$);
    \coordinate (opamp plus) at (opamp.+);
    \coordinate (opamp minus) at (opamp.-); 
    \draw (opamp plus) -- (opamp plus|-(0, 3.2));
    \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 1.2)$) to[R, n=R4, -*] (opamp plus|-(0,3.2));
    \node[below] at (R4.s) {\(R_4\)}; 
    \draw (opamp minus) -- (opamp minus|-(0, 0.5));
    \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, -1.2)$) to[R, l=\(R_5\), -*] (opamp minus|-(0, 0.8));
    \draw (0, 4) -- (2, 4);
    \draw (4, 4) -- (opamp plus|-(0, 4));
    \draw (13.2, 4) -- (opamp plus);
    \draw (0, 0) -- (9, 0);
    \draw (9, 0) to[R, n=R6, ] (opamp minus|-(0, 0));
    \node[below] at (R6.s) {\(R_6\)};
    \draw (13.2, 0) -- (opamp minus);
    \node[ground] at (8, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So can anyone help me how to move resistors R4 and R5 to left like in the picture.Thanks in advance :)

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code have several errors. For example you should write `(opamp minus)|-(0, 0);` instead of `(opamp minus|-(0, 0));`. Also, you should provide a MWE, starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Other thing. The `circuitikz` package provides `\begin{circuitikz}` and `\end{circuitikz}` for drawing circuits.

Comment: @Vesne did you try `xshift=-2cm` inside  `[R, n=R4, -*, xshift=-2cm]`

Comment: @jsbibra Jeah I tried but same thing happen

Comment: @JuanCastaño probably the existence of the `circuitikz` environment was, in hindsight, an error. It's just an alias for `tikzpicture` and confounds a lot of other packages. My suggestion is not to use it (I should state that in the manual, and remove it from there, I know...)

Comment: @Rmano, I didn't now it. Thanks!!

Comment: @JuanCastaño about your first comment: `(a |- b)` and `(a) |- (b)` are both valid, but different: the first is a coordinate, the second a path specification. Now you are right that probably the one you selected should have been written `(a |- 0,0)`...

Comment: @Vesne have a look at the answer below please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Path components are always drawn in the middle of the start and endpoints of the `to` command. So if you need a piece of wire, then a component,  you do state exactly that:

```latex
    \draw (a) -- ++(0.5,0) to[R] (b);
```

So, as a tutorial point, I would write the op-amp piece of the circuit like the following. Notice that you can change the look of the circuit just changing *one number* — the rest will follow suit. So if you change the `\def\upwardshift{1.0}` you will have a taller circuit, and if you change the `1.5` in  `\draw (OA up) -- ++(-1.5,0) ...` you will have a wider circuit, *without* having to touch any other number or coordinate around.

Heavily commented to show usage.

```
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    % everything will be relative to the position of the op amp chosen here.
    % better use the `noinv input up` option than yscale=-1 so that the power supply
    % anchors are not updown!
    \node[op amp, xscale=-1, noinv input up](OA) at (0,0) {\ctikzflipx{\texttt{oa1}}};
    % let's create the nodes above the op amp + and below op amp -.
    % I am defining the shift here to reuse it for the symmetric one.
    \def\upwardshift{1.0}
    \draw (OA.+) to[short, -*] ++(0, \upwardshift) coordinate(OA up);
    \draw (OA.-) to[short, -*] ++(0, -\upwardshift) coordinate(OA down);
    % we want the resistor a bit off to the left; I'll mark the cable end position
    % to reuse it on the other side. Just change the numbers here if you want
    % to adjust positions, the others branches will follow suit.
    \draw (OA up) -- ++(-1.5,0) coordinate(tmp) to[R=$R_4$] ++(-2,0) coordinate(r4 left)
        % vertical connection in the same path to have a nice joined line, using
        % the perpendicular coordinate system: vertically down (r4 left), horizontally (OA down)
        -- (r4 left |- OA down)
        % the other R
        to[R=$R_5$] (tmp |- OA down) -- (OA down);
    % connect the op amp output
    \draw (OA.out) to[short, -*] (OA.out -| r4 left) coordinate(OA out);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now change the upward shift to `0.75` and the first explicit wire to `2.5` and:

[image]

This technique makes your circuits highly reusable --- you can come up with a rich database of sub-circuits that can be readjusted and re-used easily. If you use explicit coordinates, you need to change lots of them to adapt the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz, circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=1.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw 
        (0, 0)  to  [L, l=\(L_1\)] (0, 4)
                to  (2,4);
        \draw 
        (2, 0)  to  [C, l=\(C_1\), *-*](2,4) 
                to  [R, l=\(R_1\), *-*] (4, 4)
                to  (8,4);
        \draw 
        (4, 0)  to  [C, l=\(C_2\), *-*] (4, 4);
        \draw 
        (6, 0)  to  [R, l=\(R_2\), *-] (6, 2)
                to  [diode,fill=black, l=\(D_1\), -*](6, 4)
                to  (8,4) coordinate(d2)
                to  [diode,fill=black, l=\(D_2\), *-] (8, 2)
                to  [R, l=\(R_3\),  ] (8, 0)coordinate(r3)
                to  (0,0);
        \node[op amp, xscale=-1, yscale=-1] (opamp) at (12, 2) {};
%       \draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1.5, 0)$) to[short, *-] (opamp.out);
        \draw (opamp.out)   to [short,-*]   ++(-1.5,0) 
                            to ++(0,1.2) 
                            to[R, l=R4]     ++(1.6,0)coordinate[label=](r4)
                            to(r4)-|(opamp.+)--(opamp.+);
        \draw (opamp.out)   to [short,-*]   ++(-1.5,0) 
                            to ++(0,-1.2) 
                            to[R, l=R5]     ++(1.6,0)coordinate[label=](r5)
                            to(r5)-|(opamp.-)--(opamp.-);
        \draw(d2)-|(opamp.+) (r3)-|(opamp.-);

        \node[ground] at (8, 0){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```