# Help with moving something around in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

So I have a couple of questions, this is the circuit that I have currently [image: the circuit i have]

and I was wondering if i could make the space where the R1 is a bit wider (just around 5 more milimeters on each side, if I could somehow make the R6 below the R5 directly (that is make the part where the R4 and the R5 are just a tad bit smaller). My code is below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) to[L, l=\(L_1\)] (0, 4);
\draw (2, 0) to[C, l=\(C_1\), *-*] (2, 4);
\draw (2, 4) to[R, l=\(R_1\), *-*] (4, 4);
\draw (4, 0) to[C, l=\(C_2\), *-*] (4, 4);
\draw (6, 0) to[R, l=\(R_2\), *-] (6, 2);
\draw[fill=black] (6, 2) to[diode, l=\(D_1\), -*] (6, 4);
\draw (8, 0) to[R, l_=\(R_3\), *-] (8, 2);
\draw[fill=black] (8, 4) to[diode, l=\(D_2\), *-] (8, 2);
\node[op amp, xscale=-1, yscale=-1] (opamp) at (14, 2) {};
\draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 0)$) to[short, *-] (opamp.out);
\draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 0)$) -- ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 1.5)$);
\draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 0)$) -- ($(opamp.out) + (-1, -1.5)$);
\coordinate (opamp plus) at (opamp.+);
\coordinate (opamp minus) at (opamp.-);
\draw (opamp plus) -- (opamp plus|-(0, 3.5));
\draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, 1.5)$) to[R, n=R4, -*] (opamp plus|-(0, 3.5));
\node[below] at (R4.s) {\(R_4\)};
\draw (opamp minus) -- (opamp minus|-(0, 0.5));
\draw ($(opamp.out) + (-1, -1.5)$) to[R, l=\(R_5\), -*] (opamp minus|-(0, 0.5));
\draw (0, 4) -- (2, 4);
\draw (4, 4) -- (opamp plus|-(0, 4));
\draw (15.2, 4) -- (opamp plus);
\draw (0, 0) -- (8, 0);
\draw (8, 0) to[R, l=\(R_6\)] (opamp minus|-(0, 0));
\draw (15.2, 0) -- (opamp minus);
\draw (8,0) node [ocirc, ground, scale=1.5]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: When you use code that is copied from another post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592308/38080 please cite it (and it's a bit edgy to say "my code")

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592361/38080

Answer (score 2):

Giving that the circuit is made with absolute coordinates, you have to change a lot of them. Change `\draw (2, 4) to[R, l=\(R_1\), *-*] (4, 4);` with a (5,4) at the end it will do. Then move the rest of the coordinates accordingly.

Comment: Or use some other code from another answer that uses relative positioning only...

Comment: Hi Rmano would there be a way for me to communicate with you privately I only have a couple of quick questions because I see no way of sending messages here

Comment: Sorry, no. Please use the accepted communication ways. I try to help when I can. LaTeX and circuitikz are powerful systems, but you have to dedicate them time to learn; they're the completely wrong tool in a hurry. I maintain (and I wrote a good half) a 200 page manual for circuitikz!

Comment: I can create a chat room but they're not private.